# "See an example"

Tags: expressions, verbs

Is it correct to talk about a product on a website and then show a button "See an example" next to it?

**I wonder if the verb "see" is correct here** or if I must use another verb, like "Watch an example" or "Check out an example".

Comment: What is the context, what is the content that the example is for, and what level of formality are you trying to achieve with your target audience? With this information, it will be easier to determine what is most appropriate for your audience.

Comment: @AndrewFan It is for a website that prints menus for restaurants. Near a product I want to allow the customer to see a real example of that menu design, before using it.

Comment: Since it's not video content, 'watch' is not appropriate for this scenario. 'Check out' tends to be more casual/street language, which does not seem to be applicable given what you are doing, so I would definitely vouch for RustyUK's answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a native English speaker and having been involved in many web design projects, I can tell you that you are absolutely correct. "See an example." is perfect for what you need.